# Chi-square from tables separated in output

Tags: r

I tried to create a table with three variables. Now I want to run a Chi-square on both of the outputs. How do I run a Chi-square on the output , , = 1 and again on output , , = 2?

```
> emphasis<-table(Pilot$emphasis.GI, Pilot$emphasis.race, Pilot$required.learning)
> emphasis
, ,  = 1

   
     2  3  4
  2 11  5  0
  3  2  8  0
  4  0  0  0

, ,  = 2

   
     2  3  4
  2  0  0  0
  3  0  2  0
  4  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a 3D `array`.  We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 3` and apply the test

```
apply(emphasis, 3, chisq.test)
```

---

Or use a `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', dim(emphasis)[3])
for(i in seq_along(out)) out[[i]] <- chisq.test(emphasis[,, i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `asplit` over the third dimension and run `chisq.test` with `Map`

```
Map(chisq.test,asplit(emphasis, 3))
```